# Не могу загрузить «props» данные

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

В моем проекте я загружаю данные с этой страницы: 
http://seo-gmbh.eu/json/api_sunds.php?action=init_data_for_index
(с помощью Axios) 

Эти данные были загружены на мою главную страницу. 
После этого я пытаюсь передать эти данные через `«props»` в компонент центрального контента моей страницы. 
Мой дебаггер Vue показал мне, что данные получены правильно: 

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в моем компоненте центрального контента я не могу получить эти данные для отображения в своем HTML-коде. 
Я мог бы получить часть этих данных следующим образом: 
`dbIndex.data`
Но если я попытаюсь получить эти данные реквизита глубже, как в этом случае: 
`dbIndex.data.init_data_for_index` 
Я получаю сообщение об ошибке `"Cannot read property 'init_data_for_index' "`. 

**Мой вопрос:** 
Как правильно получить эти данные в моем случае?

```js
<template>
 <section class="center_content_index">

    <ul class="ul_1">

        <li class="li_3">
          {{  dbIndex.data.init_data_for_index  }}
        </li>

    </ul>
    <!--  <ul class="ul_1"> end -->

  </section>
</template>


<script>
import LiServiceApp from '~/components/CenterContentIndexApp/LiServiceApp';

  export default{

    props:['dbIndex'],

    components:{
      LiServiceApp,
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: может, на момент рендеринга шаблона, данных еще нет?

Comment: Cамо собой. Вопрос в том как решить эту асинхронную проблему или как минимум проверить ее наличие?

Comment: повесте watch на dbIndex, с параметром deep:true. Так Вы сможете отслеживать изменение. Но я бы решал эту проблему на уровне роутера иил родителя этого компонента

Comment: А на уровне родителя компонента каким образом можно попробовать это решить?

Comment: с помощью v-if, отображать компонент, после получения ответа